# How do you split a single python list element into several independent list elements?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a .txt file that reads exactly like this:

> 0,Hello,01,Cooking,02,Biking,13,My Hawaii Vacation,14,Freezing weather in Iowa,0

The code I have so far is:

```
a = open('wiki.txt','r')
ar = a.readlines()
biglistA = map(lambda each:each.strip('\n'), ar)
```

Which gives me output of:

```
['0,Hello,0', '1,Cooking,0', '2,Biking,1', '3,My Hawaii Vacation,1', '4,Freezing weather in Iowa,0']
```

I need to get this to look like:

```
[['0','Hello','0'], ['1','Cooking','0'], ['2','Biking','1'], ['3','My Hawaii Vacation','1'], ['4','Freezing weather in Iowa','0']]
```

The final product needs to be a nested list with each element being referenced, i.e:

```
print newlist[1][1]
```

'Cooking'

**That is the desired output.  If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Are you sure that your `.txt` file reads exactly like that?  It seems to me that you're missing some newlines in there...

Comment: map with lambda is ugly and slow. `[x.strip('\n') for x in ar]` does the same thing and is faster. Better yet combine a strip and split as mgilson does

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you need something like:

```
with open('wiki.txt') as fin:
    bigListA = [ line.strip().split(',') for line in fin ]
```

Answer (score 1):

A strange requirement.  I guess a regex would be the best bet:

```
import re
with open('wiki.txt') as f:
  s = f.read()
newlist = [triple.split(',') for triple in re.findall(r'\d,.*?,\d', s)]
```

Or, continuing on from where you were at already, just apply a list comprehension like:

```
newlist = [x.split(',') for x in biglistA]
```